# Ripping sound from online video through soundcard?

Tags: windows, video, ripping, audio-recording

There are a couple of videos on the Web whose soundtracks I'd like to rip so I can listen to them at the gym, but all of the web apps like KeepVid that I tried failed downloading them.

As a work-around, I'll just play the videos and record the soundtrack for later listening.

Are there good applications for Windows, free or affordable, that will let me record whatever is being played on the soundcard?

Thank you.

Comment: Are they in youtube? If so you should try DVDVideoSoft.com (http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/guides/dvd/convert-YouTube-to-MP3.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is dependent on the soundcard, especially if mixing is done in hardware. Creative soundcards have a special mic channel called "What-U-Hear", not sure about other sound cards.  If you don't have one available, you might have luck searching for a "Virtual Sound Card".  There is a virtual ESD sound card which would allow you to send an audio stream to a recording server, but I believe it is long unsupported and doesn't work with recent versions of windows.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My sound card doesn't seem to provide this, but it turns out that Audacity supports recording whatever is being played on the sound card.