# Ripping sound from online video?

Tags: windows, audio, video, ripping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ripping sound from online video through soundcard?](https://superuser.com/questions/147984/ripping-sound-from-online-video-through-soundcard)

**Edit from the author**: This thread is NOT duplicate, but an extension of a very limited question.  Please let this question to be answered.

Hello

There are a couple of videos on the Web whose soundtracks I'd like to rip to MP3 (so I could listen to them off the computer).

What webapps/applications (for Windows), free or affordable, are there that will let me record those videos?

(That is following this [SO thread](https://superuser.com/questions/147984/ripping-sound-from-online-video-through-soundcard) that didn't get many replies, nor offer extensive options except for the sound card option)

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software related questions **only**. Phones, websites, and electronic devices are considered **off topic** as defined by the site scope laid out in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Well, the device is probably an MP3 player.  He might be trying to ask how to extract audio from video files into an MP3 format.  Is that what you were asking Tal Galili?

Comment: I don't see why this is off topic, he's asking how to extract audio from online videos. In any case this is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/147984/ripping-sound-from-online-video-through-soundcard . Audacity is a freeware that will let you record audio from your sound card

Comment: Josh K - I wish to extract audio from video to MP3. so this is not off topic.

Comment: Josh K - I think this thread is not off topic or duplicate.

The thread you mention as duplicate is mentioned by me in my postings, and it is not duplicate since he wanted help with just recording through the soundcard.  And I am asking about all possible options.  A shame this thread will get closed.

Answer (score 3):

If by any chance "videos on the Web" means youtube there is always: http://www.listentoyoutube.com/ just paste the video link and click download to get the mp3.
Other than that there is a program mp3mymp3 mp3mymp3 DOT com that worked for me, for recording whatever my sound card played.
Hope this helped :)
(only was allowed to post 1 URL :-/ )
Greetings from Germany!